# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in "x: element.position().get(x),"

Tags: javascript

This is the code that leads to the error:

```
x: element.position().get(x),
```

This is the full code:

```
direct.forEach(
  descendants.add(function(element) {
    {
      nodes: {
        data: {
          id: "emptynodefor" + element.id(),
          x: element.position().get(x),
          y: width
        }
      },
      edges: {
        data: {
          from: "emptynodefor" + element.id(),
          to: element.id()
        }
      }
    }
  }))
```

I really don't know what details to add here.

Comment: They don't really look that similar to me. The unexpected token is `:`, apparently. Can you put the full snippet here?

Comment: yes please provide a [mcve]

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? The problem is that the first `{` after `function(element) {` is the start of a block. I think you expect it to be an object, but you don't actually *do* anything with it -- `return` it, assign it to a variable, etc. Even if JS interpreted this as an object instead of a block (for example, if you surrounded it with parentheses like `({ ... })`), you'd still have an object just sitting there, not doing anything or going anywhere.

Comment: Your function has no instructions, just an inline object declaration.  Maybe you are missing a `return`?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a return statement. `function(element) { return
    {
      nodes: {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
direct.forEach(function(element) {
  descendants.add(
    {
      nodes: {
        data: {
          id: "emptynodefor" + element.id(),
          x: element.position().get(x),
          y: width
        }
      },
      edges: {
        data: {
          from: "emptynodefor" + element.id(),
          to: element.id()
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

?

Because the code you have makes no sense.

You're passing a function to `descendants.add()`, but the function body contains what looks like an object literal, which is a syntax error at that point because you're not doing anything with it (returning it, assigning it to a variable, etc.), so JavaScript interprets it as a block of code (with syntax errors).

Your code would then pass the return value of `descendants.add()` to `direct.forEach()`, which doesn't look intentional either.